# How do I get an imagebutton ID in C#?

Tags: c#, imagebutton

I know I can get an imagebutton's X&Y, but how do I get it's ID?

I'd like to start by printing it to a label at first.
later I would like to use it in a switch case - any different case would change the imagebutton.imageurl to a different image, but speicifically do it for the imagebutton I just clicked on.

I tried

```
Label1.Text = Convert.ToString((ImageButton)sender);
```

But this is the result

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton
```

As a result which isn't a lot of help, because I need the specific control's ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImageButton b = sender as ImageButton;
if (b != null) {
    string theId = b.ClientID;

    // Change the URL
    b.ImageUrl = "/whatever/you/like.png";
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it's working!
Is it possible to use this in order to change the current imagebuttons ImageURL, like so? ((ImageButton)sender).ID).ImageUrl ="correct_quiz.gif";

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean this?

```
  Label1.Text = ((ImageButton)sender).ID
```

**Update** (as per your comment):

To change the ImageURL, you would use this:

```
((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl ="correct_quiz.gif";
```

Or if you'd want to combine the two things, I'd recommend this:

```
ImageButton button = ((ImageButton)sender);
Label1.Text = button.ID;
button.ImageUrl = "correct_quiz.gif";
```

Comment: I guess I did! :) Thanks!
Is it possible to use this in order to change the current imagebuttons ImageURL, like so?

 ((ImageButton)sender).ID).ImageUrl ="correct_quiz.gif";

Answer (score 2):

```
((ImageButton)sender).ClientID
```

or if you want just the ID

```
((ImageButton)sender).ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use ImageButton's ID property